# php email form on 1and1

Tags: php, email

I am trying to combine the name field with the email field so that the email will be delivered like:

From: Name of Person Filling Out Form (email_address.com)

Goal: (**Email From Line** would contain the person's name and email).

I am using 1and1's mail.php function and there are no instructions on how to do this.

Is this even possible?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

echo '<link href="new/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">';

// THE BELOW LINE STATES THAT IF THE SUBMIT BUTTON
// WAS PUSHED, EXECUTE THE PHP CODE BELOW TO SEND THE 
// MAIL. IF THE BUTTON WAS NOT PRESSED, SKIP TO THE CODE
// BELOW THE "else" STATEMENT (WHICH SHOWS THE FORM INSTEAD).
if ( isset ( $_POST [ 'buttonPressed' ] )){

// REPLACE THE LINE BELOW WITH YOUR E-MAIL ADDRESS.
$to = 'myemail.com' ;
$subject = 'From PHP contact page' ;

// NOT SUGGESTED TO CHANGE THESE VALUES
$message = $_POST [ "message" ] ;
$headers = 'From: ' . $_POST[ "from" ] . PHP_EOL ;
$name = $_POST['name'];
mail ( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ;

// THE TEXT IN QUOTES BELOW IS WHAT WILL BE 
// DISPLAYED TO USERS AFTER SUBMITTING THE FORM.

echo '<div id="msg_sent"> Your e-mail has been sent. You should receive a reply within a week. </div>';}

?>
```

Thank you if you know anything!

Comment: You want to use this in your headers: `From: Name of Person <email@address.com>`.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3481

Comment: P.S. You probably don't want to use `PHP_EOL` with the email headers.  Email wants the headers to use `\r\n`, and `PHP_EOL` might not always be that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I am using 1and1's mail.php function and there are no instructions on how to do this.
>
>   Is this even possible?"*

Yes, it is possible.

Add an email form element `<input type="text" name="email">` if you don't already have one, then do:

```
$email   = $_POST['email'];
$name    = $_POST['name'];
$headers = "From: ". $name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n";
```

Mail stands at going to Spam if the `From` is only a name, instead of containg an Email address.

You should also use [`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) for your email variable, in order to validate it.

I.e.:

```
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
  {
  echo "E-mail is not valid.";
  }
```

---

***Sidenote:***
Rocket's comments make sense in regards to `PHP_EOL` which is why my example contains `\r\n`.

Comment: Also, in regards to my downvote. I always research before I post to Stack, I honestly could not find clear instructions on how to do this (googled for two days). Part of the problem is not knowing the correct terms to put into Google, which is why Stack is sooooo useful.